# callback for spring integration with mirth synchronous message

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-classic, mirth

I have integration project wit setup as follows.

Application1(Spring integration) --> AMQ --> Mirth --> Internet --> Mirth --> AMQ --> (Spring integration)Application 2

The above flow messages are passing happens in both ways and I want to implement something like this.

When I do initiate request message(outbound) from Application 1 it goes to Application 2(as inbound) and send zero to Many messages(outbound) to Application 1. My requirement is to keep waiting for all responses and do something.

Is there any features support for this in mirth spring?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need correlation and aggregation functionality in the Application1. When you send the message to the AMQ you specify some `correlationKey` and also send this message to the aggregator.

Then you have a Message Driven Channel Adapter to listen to the queue for that multi-reply. Hope you know during send how much replies you are suppose to wait.

So, all the message from the replies are sent to the same aggregator for correlation with the request and grouping for the final reply. All this time you will be blocked to wait the result from the aggregator's output channel.

Absolutely not sure is the Mirth how to cook it for this solution...

Comment: Thank Bilan it will help.